# Изменение стилей при наведении мыши

Tags: javascript

Нужно поменять CSS-свойство у нескольких элементов следующим образом. Есть несколько элементов и нужно чтобы при наведении мыши на один (любой) менялся цвет остальных. Как можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: приведите пример разметки, и что вы сами пытались сделать

Comment: может css справиться с этим? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/a8ogkgLu/

Comment: css не справиться так как элементы элементы не с одним родителем. 
Вот пример кода: http://codepen.io/Fess/pen/adOgRN?editors=110
Нужно что бы при наведении на один сектор(любой) менялся цвет допустим на серый у все других секторов

Comment: добавьте этот код в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если элементы совсем никак не поддаются группировке, то можно поступить, например, следующим образом:

```js
function getTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return (e.target || e.srcElement);
};
function onMouseOver(e) {
    var target = getTarget(e);
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
        if (elements[i] == target)
            elements[i].setAttribute("data-selected", 1);
        else
            elements[i].setAttribute("data-selected", 0);
}
function onMouseOut() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Test");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
        elements[i].removeAttribute("data-selected");
}
```

```css
.test {
    padding: 1em;
}
.test[data-selected="1"] {
    background-color: #fdd;
}
.test[data-selected="0"] {
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <span class="test" onmouseover="onMouseOver(event);" onmouseout="onMouseOut();">
        Span 1
    </span>
    <span class="test" onmouseover="onMouseOver(event);" onmouseout="onMouseOut();">
        Span 2
    </span>
    <span class="test" onmouseover="onMouseOver(event);" onmouseout="onMouseOut();">
       Span 3
    </span>
    <span class="test" onmouseover="onMouseOver(event);" onmouseout="onMouseOut();">
       Span 4
    </span>
</body>
```

(В сниппете почему-то не отрабатывает `onmouseout`, хотя если код поместить в отдельный файл, он работает нормально.)

Если же необходимые элементы всё же можно каким-либо образом запихнуть в единый контейнер, то задача сильно упрощается и реализуема на чистом CSS без использования JavaScript:

```css
.test {
    padding: 1em;
}
.container:hover .test {
    background-color: #ddf;
}
.container:hover .test:hover {
    background-color: #fdd;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <span class="test">
            Span 1
        </span>
        <span class="test">
            Span 2
        </span>
        <span class="test">
           Span 3
        </span>
        <span class="test">
           Span 4
        </span>
    </div>
```